# Opening a multi-currency bank account abroad

Tags: banking, currency

I'm a Hungarian citizen, and currently living in Hungary.

I'm planning a long holiday trip in Europe, visiting a few countries like Switzerland, UK, and Belgium.

My bank account in Hungary has HUF currency, and I think it would be very inefficient to use this account with my visa card to cover my expenses while I'm on trip. In my understanding, that would involve currency conversion on every ATM usage at a very high rate.

I would like to avoid this, so what I'm thinking about is to open a bank account abroad, and use Transferwise to transfer my HUF to that account.

Do you think this makes sense? Are there any more effective way to save money?

Can you recommend a good bank to open an account for this? It should be able to handle multiple currencies, and i would like to open it online without making a trip just for this. I have no country of preference.

Comment: Specific service provider recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: OK, i don't really need that, just an indication if my theory would work

Comment: Possible query for travel SE?  You'll find more international travelers there. http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25752) on travel.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid this, so what I'm thinking about is to open a bank account abroad, and use Transferwise to transfer my HUF to that account.
>   Do you think this makes sense?

It does make sense. The challange is to find a Bank that will allow you to open an account online.

> Are there any more effective way to save money?

Try prepaid cards. You should be able to get these from normal Banks in Hungary or other reputed financial institutions. You will have a visibility of the rates and it would be one time conversion.